# DatePicker in jQuery Not Showing Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to do a date picker in jQuery. I put these within the head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And from this part of my code in JavaScript is calling the date picker:

```
case "mhc":
        if (mhc_overlay == null) {
               mhc_overlay = new google.maps.HeatmapLayer();
        }
        if (!mhc_overlay_visible) {
            mhc_overlay_visible = true;
            $("#MHC").removeClass("menuLink");
            $("#MHC").addClass("menuLink_selected");

            visibleOverlays.push("mhc");

            var content = "";
            content += "<label for='startDate'>Date :</label>";
            content += "<input name='startDate' id='startDate' class='date-picker' />";

            filterWindowContent.push({ id: "mhc", label: label, content: content });
            showFilterWindow();

            map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
            addToCurrentOverlayList("loadedmhc", "mhc", "MHC Live Map");

        }
        break;
```

There is no error message showing but just that the date picker does not show calendar when selected. I wonder why is it so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a debugger; inside javascript code and check exception in chrome using F12 key

Comment: Is there any way to call the $function when input field for date picker on selected? Currently it's not firing when selected

Comment: Looks like you have messed some code together, looks like you got some Google maps javascript into your date-picker

Comment: Do you have jQuery included? As it seems in your code you only include jQueryUI but no jQuery library.

Comment: Because what I am trying to do is if this layer as selected, it will pop up a filter window. Only this part of codes calling the showFilterWindow() which take in the date picker as content. I wonder is there any alternate way/solutions?

Comment: Any clues? Really appreciate the helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the textfield dynamically in the document. So you need to call the datepicker() function after showFilterWindow() function. I think after that it will work properly. Put your jQuery datepicker function in a separate function. Like this:

```
function showdatepicker() {
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
}
```

and call this showdatepicker() function after showFilterWindow() function. Like this:

```
 case "mhc":
    if (mhc_overlay == null) {
           mhc_overlay = new google.maps.HeatmapLayer();
    }
    if (!mhc_overlay_visible) {
        mhc_overlay_visible = true;
        $("#MHC").removeClass("menuLink");
        $("#MHC").addClass("menuLink_selected");

        visibleOverlays.push("mhc");

        var content = "";
        content += "<label for='startDate'>Date :</label>";
        content += "<input name='startDate' id='startDate' class='date-picker' />";

        filterWindowContent.push({ id: "mhc", label: label, content: content });
        showFilterWindow();
        showdatepicker();

        map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
        addToCurrentOverlayList("loadedmhc", "mhc", "MHC Live Map");

    }
    break;
```

I think it will work. If not, please share a link so I can check it online.

Comment: Yeah it works. But it only shows month and year to select. Is there any way to add in date as well?

Comment: I think you need to change the dateFormat. Your current date format is : dateFormat: 'MM yy'

Comment: It does not work even though I added dd. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/BXV8z/1/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the jsfiddle link. I have modified your jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BXV8z/3/ I have also added two external resources jquery ui css and jquery ui library in the left hand side. I have also fixed the name  of the classes that you were using. There was an extra single quote in the class "date-picker"

Comment: Would you mind to provide me the CDN for both the external resources that you added?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: @Carol you can find easily these CDN from the jQuery official sites :)
Or you can use the google CDN for these :
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: Let's say I wanted to get the user input for startDate, all I needed to do is: var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate"); ? Does it take whatever user input and store as variable?

Comment: then you need to use document.getElementById('startDate').value or you can use jquery as well : jQuery('#startDate').val()

Comment: Thanks a lot! But would you mind to help em solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051715/undefined-is-not-a-function-javascript ?

Comment: @Carol I never worked on heatmap. But I think you should learn to debug the issues yourself. Like Felix says in the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jquery library before calling jQuery UI:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It throws me error message of Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' after adding the line above

Comment: That's because you include jQuery version 1.11.0, the .live() method was removed in jQuery version 1.9, see http://api.jquery.com/live/